# How to navigate between instances of selected text in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, selection, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Sublime Text 3 highlights all instances of currently selected text. Is there any shortcut to navigate cursor to the next / previous instance (copy) of selected text?

So far, I've only managed to find out [some information](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/editing/editing.html) about adding more instances to current selection (expanding it) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, skipping current instance (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and deselecting it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>), which actually is a soft undo, not a real command.

I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to go to next instance of selected text and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to undo. But, since these shortcuts operates on selection, this is not, what I'm looking for.

Actually, I'm asking, is there any way to have this as simple as pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to go to the next instance or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> to go to previous.

If this is not solved by default, then what commands should be tied to user-defined keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: `Ctrl+F3` to find next occurrence of the selected text, or `Ctrl+Shift+F3` for the previous one.

.


(Just typing this because the selected answer is way too complicated, it cost me 15 minutes of extra time that was unneeded.) See Florent Daligales answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40906578/2321785 )

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Yes**, all you need to do is **edit your key bindings** (Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Key Bindings User) for **"find_under"**. Copy & paste this into your bindings and set your keys (defaults are "alt+super+g" and shift+alt+super+g)

```
{ "keys": ["alt+super+g"], "command": "find_under" },
{ "keys": ["shift+alt+super+g"], "command": "find_under_prev" },
```

Comment: This is the thing, I've been looking for. However, I must point out, that this is just a bit better and faster solution, than [the one given previously](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25931864/1469208), in which you have to press `Ctrl+F` to open search box, before you can navigate between instances of selected text. Your solution reduces just this one step -- allows to navigate through all instances of selected text without opening search box.

Comment: Super = the Windows key

Comment: On the Mac it's CMD+OPTION+G, by default.

Comment: I find using just alt+up and alt+down much easier on brain and fingers

Answer (score 6):

I also needed to navigate through occurrences of a word in a quicker way than:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- Type world to find
- Press <kbd>F3</kbd> to find next occurrence.

And I just found this tip:

Select occurrence

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to find next occurrence, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> for the previous one.

At this point the occurrence is already the search text, so you can simply use <kbd>F3</kbd> for next one and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> for previous, if you need to navigate between more occurrences.

I hope this also helps you.

Comment: This is what works for me in Ubuntu. Whereas the key combinations in answers above did not work in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

I may be misunderstanding your question but what you are asking seems pretty simple and I wonder if that means you might mean something else. Anyway here's an answer that I hope is what you are looking for.

First, ensure that you have the following set to true in your preferences:

```
// If true, the selected text will be copied into the find panel when it's
// shown.
// On OS X, this value is overridden in the platform specific settings, so
// you'll need to place this line in your user settings to override it.
"find_selected_text": true,
```

Select the string you are interested in.

Search in current file [OS X Cmd+F :: Windows Ctrl+F]

Now you can step through the matches:

- Forward [OS X Cmd+G :: Windows F4]
- Back [OS X Cmd+Shift+G :: Windows Shift+F4]

Some more here :: http://www.cheatography.com/njovin/cheat-sheets/sublime-text-2-keyboard-shortcuts-windows/

What am I missing in your question?

Comment: FWIW, I had exactly the same thought :-)

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, as there isn't any better. However, this is not what I expected / asked for, because this is modifying search query, which I'd like to avoid. I already aware of this technique. What I was looking, was a simpler way, without modifying current search query. When you double click any word, Sublime Text 3 marks all occurrences of the same word in current document. Other editors does the same and also allows to move cursor to the next / previous occurrence. All completely independently of current search query. Apparently Sublime Text 3 doesn't have such functionality.

Comment: Ah ha - I see what I was missing now, I thought there must be something - I don't know a way to do what you are seeking without using search but me not knowing and it not being available in ST is not the same thing - I only know what I know. Hopefully someone who really knows will add to the  conversation.

Comment: Accepting your answer and accepting [_Ryan Urie_'s one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32535198/1469208), because this is exactly, what I've been looking for. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a mac, and this has sort of already been mentioned, but it doesn't require altering the hotkey menu and works well enough for me.

cmd+K keeps your highlight but **deselects** it

cmd+D expands your **selection** (now empty thanks to cmd+k) by including the next occurrence

> highlight a string (one that recurs)
>
> while holding cmd -> press K, then press D
>
> alternating back and forth as many times as necessary.
>
> Each time D is alternated to, your highlight and selection jump to only the next occurrence.