# Sublimetext find usages, references

Tags: reference, sublimetext3, go-to-definition

I'm using SublimeText3 and wanted to know if there is an option (package) which can be used to

- Find references within the file.
- Find references within the folder.
- Goto definition.

I found a command called Goto->Reference, but this does not work for the current file and seems buggy.

I also found a package called wordhighlighter which is very useful.https://github.com/SublimeText/WordHighlight.  I want to use this to navigate among highlighted words.  Is there any keyboard shortcut to achieve this?  There is an option to expand and collapse the selection but thats about it.

Answer (score 0):

For someone else who comes up with the same issue, I found the answer here

[How to navigate between instances of selected text in Sublime Text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923531/how-to-navigate-between-instances-of-selected-text-in-sublime-text-3)

{ "keys": ["alt+super+g"], "command": "find_under" },
{ "keys": ["shift+alt+super+g"], "command": "find_under_prev" },