# How to select the previous instance of selected text in Sublime Text 3d

Tags: sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts, selection, sublimetext, key-bindings

I am using Sublime Text 3 on Windows.

I can select the next instance of the currently selected text, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Is there keybinding for selecting and moving the cursor to the previous instance of the selected text?

For example, a keybinding that will go from this state:

[image: State 1]

To this state:

[image: State 2].

In this specific case, I can do that using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (skipping the current selection),
but in larger files it's more complicated.

I looked a in the key bindings file but the keys I tried did not work:

```
    { "keys": ["shift+f3"], "command": "find_prev" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+f3"], "command": "find_under" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+f3"], "command": "find_under_prev" },
```

Also, I looked at "[How to navigate between instances of selected text in Sublime Text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923531/how-to-navigate-between-instances-of-selected-text-in-sublime-text-3)", but that is talking about selecting the previous instance, it selects the previous instance instead of the current, selected, instance.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime supports "Find Previous" using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to find the currently selected text on Mac OS. It's under the "Find" menu.

I'm sure there's a Windows equivalent because in the default "Key Bindings" in the preferences it's

```
"super+shift+g"
```

in Sublime-ese.

Comment: This is a great shortcut, but it doesn't select both occurances, just jumps the cursor to the previous occurance. Which is still good, but not quite what was asked